# Pyspark - write a dataframe into 2 different csv files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to save a single DataFrame into 2 different csv files (splitting the DataFrame) - one would include just the header and another would include the rest of the rows.

I want to save the 2 files under the same directory so Spark handling all the logic would be the best option if possible instead of splitting the csv file using pandas.

what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just do a subprocess call and do it with bash. should be easier that way.

Comment: @philantrovert Processing ~1TB file for example may be quite slow, even with bash ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you've got Dataset called "df".

You can:
Option one: write twice:

```
df.write.(...).option("header", "false").csv(....)
df.take(1).option("header", "true").csv() // as far as I remember, someone had problems with saving DataFrame without rows -> you must write at least one row and then manually cut this row using normal Java or Python file API
```

Or you can write once with header = true and then manually cut the header and place it in new file using normal Java API

Comment: thanks for your answer. one more question, wouldn't Spark write 2 files into different directory? would it be possible to save them in the same directory?

Comment: Wouldn't the second line write 2 lines? `take(1)` would take first row of data and `header, true` will write the header as well?

Comment: @Young You should write to separate folder and then move files. Unfortunatelly, files are partitioned exactly how DataFrame was. Remember to use `repartition(1)` if you want to save all content in one file

Comment: @philantrovert As said in comment - there was a question on SO (I can't now find it), that Spark is not saving header if DataFrame is empty. So we must get at least 1 row and then manually cut this row using standard API, not Spark. But, with only one row, it would be much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Data, without header:

```
df.to_csv("filename.csv", header=False)
```

Header, without data:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df_old.columns) # data=None makes sure no rows are copied to the new dataframe
df_new.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

Comment: It;s ok, but - according to JavaDoc.. PythonDoc? ;) "
        .. note:: This method should only be used if the resulting Pandas's DataFrame is to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory."